# Employee rights regarding a change of working arrangement not written in to my contract

Tags: work-environment, job-change, contracts, united-kingdom, work-life-balance

I work of a company in the UK and have done for almost 7 years.  I work in IT supporting a number of infrastructure related projects across the EMEA region.

During this time I have always been allowed to work from home.

Also during this time the company was purchased by a multi-national company.

I have held several roles, and at no time has it ever been an issue that i work from home part of the time.  In fact I have been actively encouraged to increase the time i spend working from home as it allows me to be more flexible in terms of meetings across time zones, travel to other locations and so on.

Recently the company have introduced a global rule that unless it is specifically written in to your contract, no employee may work from home (with the exception of 'occasionally with agreement from your manager, and their manager').

All employees will now be required to work from their 'base location', which for me is ~45 mins from my home.  In total I would lose 7.5 to travel per week and incur fairly significant travel costs.  I have not had an annual pay review in 4 years because the company are apparently not making enough money, despite record share-holder pay-outs in the last 2 years.

Further to this my role 'requires' me to travel to other sites regularly.  I have written this in quotes because this is also not written in to my contract, but is expected as part of my job role (not an agreed change, one that was dictated by the company without any negotiation).  I am also expected to attend meetings (online) during non-standard hours to meet the needs of other time zones.

Although none of these changes are written in to my contract, I feel that these amount to quite significant changes to my working arrangements.  What rights do I have with regards to the levels of change?

I have tried to investigate what rights I have, but all the results I can find relate to specific written contractual changes.  Since the company say they are not changing my contract, do I have any ability to argue that this is an unfair change?

Any suggestions, links to external authoritative information or any helpful advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, we cant answer legal questions or policy questions. Honestly, you need to see a lawyer.

Comment: Give [CAB](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/) a call. Sounds like you should be protected under TUPE, but they can go into it better than I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that in this situation you have a very important and unimpeachable right:

**The right to quit.**

Clearly, this new company plays hardball with their employees, and wants to suck every drop of usefulness out of them. What you're describing sounds like nothing short of slave labor to me, and I certainly wouldn't agree to the changes unless you're in a very difficult spot financially.

You *could* go to your manager and make it clear that you refuse these working conditions, and that you want to renegotiate your contract, but unless you're truly irreplaceable (and practically no one is), they're most likely going to refuse, and probably fire you (for cause, because you're refusing to perform your responsibilities).

I suppose there's also a chance that you could contact a lawyer and challenge them on the changes they've imposed on you, but realistically, even if you win, do you think you're going to be welcomed there again?

My suggestion is to start looking for a new job ASAP.